# How to determine if a jmenuitem is a separator

Tags: java, swing, separator, jmenuitem

I have a JMenuBar filled with menuitems, including seperators. By default i have the 'Save' menu item disabled, and now I need to enable it if the user starts typing (basically user can't save the document if they haven't changed it). But my problem exists in looping through each menuitem to change the 'Save' from disabled to enabled.

I tried using a nested for loop to get the name based on the index, but I get an exception when the loop hits a separator.

int count = frame.getJMenuBar().getMenuCount();

```
for( int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    int itemCount = frame.getJMenuBar().getMenu(i).getItemCount();

    for (int j = 0; j < itemCount; j++) {
        System.out.println(frame.getJMenuBar().getMenu(i).getItem(j).getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleName());
    }
}
```

Basically I'm trying to, inside the second loop, checking for the menu name 'Save', and then enabling it that way. I don't want to hard-code the indexes incase I change the menu later on down the road.

I've also tried manually entering the indexes, instead of using loops (that's how i found out it was caused by a seperator. So now what I want to do is inside the second loop, check to see if the menuitem is a separator. But I'm not sure how to do that. I've tried searching google and came up with nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: The first thing I would do, is make use of the `Action` API, see [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).  `JMenu`s are tricky as they build their content from information gathered from the `JMenuItem` and don't tend to place them directly on the `JMenu` itself

Comment: Why don't simply have reference to the `Save` menu instead of this hack?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing happens because `getItemCount` returns separators and items. However, `getItem()` assumes there is an item at the given position. You can use this loop that checks if the item is a separator, since both `JSeparator` and `JMenuItem` extend from `Component`

```
for (int j = 0; j < itemCount; j++) {
Component component = frame.getJMenuBar().getMenu(i).getMenuComponent(j);

    if (component instanceof JSeparator)
    {
       //found a separator
    } else if (component instanceof JMenuItem)
    {
       //found a menu item
       System.out.println(((JMenuItem) component).getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleName());
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to keep a reference to the 'Save' button when you create it. Then all you would have to do is

```
saveButton.setEnabled(true);
```

instead of searching through the menus to find the button.